# Declaring and initializing variable in for loop

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, declaration

Can I write simply

```
for (int i = 0; ...
```

instead of

```
int i;
for (i = 0; ...
```

in C or C++?

(And will variable `i` be accessible inside the loop only?)

Comment: Trying this out would probably have required less effort than posting this question about it

Comment: @Don: but would give the wrong answer if you were to use a crusty old pre-standard compiler (like some people still seem to). It's better to ask, or look in the standard, than trust the behaviour of your particular compiler.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's valid in C++.

It was not legal in the original version of C.
But was adopted as part of C in C99 (when some C++ features were sort of back ported to C)
Using gcc

```
gcc -std=c99 <file>.c
```

The variable is valid inside the for statement and the statement that is looped over. If this is a block statement then it is valid for the whole of the block.

```
for(int loop = 0; loop < 10; ++loop)
{
    // loop valid in here aswell
}

// loop NOT valid here.
```

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it's legal in C++ and in C99.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly legal to do this in C99 or C++:

```
for( int i=0; i<max; ++i )
{
    //some code
}
```

and its `while` equivalent is:

```
{
    int i=0
    while( i<max )
    {
        //some code
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for` and `while` loops aren't quite equivalent.  Consider what happens if "some code" includes a `continue` statement.

Comment: I was only clarifying the scope of `i`. You can always take care that there's a `++i` before you call `continue`, but otherwise, you have a valid point.

Answer (score 3):

Acutally `for(int i=0;i<somevalue;i++)` was always drilled into me as the preferred way to define a for loop in c and c++.

As far as "i" only being accessible in your loop, you have to be care about the variable names you use.  If you declare "i" as a variable outside of the loop and are using it for something else then you are going to cause a problem when using that same variable for a loop counter.

For example:

```
int i = 10;
i = 10 + PI;
```

will be automatically changed when you hit the for loop and declare i=0

Answer (score 2):

Yes and yes.  But for C, apparently your compiler needs to be in C99 mode.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I write simply

Yes.

> (And will variable i be accessible inside the loop only?)

Depends on the compiler and its' version. 
AFAIK, in modern compilers i is accessible inside of the loop only.
Some older compilers allowed i to be accessible outside of loop as well.
Some compilers allow i to be accessed outside of the loop and warn you about non-standard behavior.

I *think* (but I'm not sure about it), that "i outside of the loop" was used somewhere in VC98 (Visual Studio 6, which AFAIK, also had a globally defined "i" variable somewhere that could lead to an extremely interesting behavior). I *think* that (microsoft) compilers made somewhere around around 2000..2003 started printing "non standard extensions used" for using i outside of loop, and eventually this functionality disappeared completely. It isn't present in visual studio 2008.

This is probably happened according to a standard but I cannot give a link or citation at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the variable outside the loop, it will be changed every time you initialize it inside loop.

```
int i = 0;
for(int e = 0; e < 10; e++)
{
 i = e;
}
```

Now, the value of `i` will change every time.

Comment: If what you're pointing out is that declaring `i` outside the for loop changes `i` possibly leading to unexpected behavior (from the point of the developer) then just say so. The code example doesn't spell it out all that clearly.