# ANSI C - initializing an array

Tags: c, arrays

What I was always doing is:

```
int arr[] = {2, 3, 4};
```

and it always worked.

I've heard of a better way to initialize new array, using the pointer:

```
int *arr = {2, 3, 4};
```

However, it doesn't work in any IDE, it throws some errors like `int differs in levels of indirection from int`, or `too many initializers`. How should I do this?

Comment: "Programming Languages"'s professor at my university

Comment: @user1615069: Either you misunderstood him, or he had a brain fart and meant `int *arr = (int []){2, 3, 4};`'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That initialization seems to work for me, on gcc, but not correctly.

```
int *arr = {2, 3, 4}; //weird behaviour, stores first value `2` as read-only

int arr[] = {2, 3, 4}; //array decl
```

The former isn't a correct way to initialize an array.

For a **char***, it makes more sense

```
char* arr = "abcde"; //Pointer to a read-only char array in memory

char[] arr = "abcde"; //Normal char array
```

---

**The difference:**

The former is written to the **Rodata** (constant, read-only data) section of the assembly, while the latter, resides in the read/write **Data-Segment**. Any attempt to change the former, might result in a **segmentation-fault**.

---

The places where the values are stored are different.

```
char* arr = "abcde";
arr[1] = 'f'; //(undefined behavior)

char[] arr2 = "abcde";
arr2[1] = 'f'; //no issue
```

Comment: Nice, a man who teaches C at the university and claims to work in some company as very well paid programmer doesn't know how to initialize arrays :P Anyways, thanks for the answers. One more - can I initialize loop variable inside of the for loop? (int i = 0; ...)

Comment: In `C`, No. In `C++`, yes. In `C99` Yes. [**More**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3189257/759019)

Comment: @user1615069 If you think your inquiry deserves another question, then ask it as another question, not as a comment on an answer you obtained.

Comment: @user1615069 That initialization does work for me, btw. Just tested. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Cthulhu -- I suspect you invoked gcc in a way that allowed for extensions.  IMHO, that code should not compile (no, I don't have a standard reference handy to quote C&V).

Further, even if somehow it is possible and it is const as you say, there is *no* "advantage" to the former -- there are no guarantees that a crash would actually occur.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps If you try to modify a value, in the `RO` data section, it **will** cause a crash. I edited answer, because with `int`, the behaviour doesn't seem defined. With `char*` on the other hand, it works exactly as stated. And no, I am running `gcc` without any such compile-time flags.

Comment: @Cthulhu -- there are no guarantees; any claims to the contrary ("it **will** cause a seg-fault") are misplaced and often specific to some platform and/or implementation.

The behavior with char is special because NUL terminated array of char is a string.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps Changed the wording a little, as I have no evidence that it will work **everywhere**.

Answer (score 6):

```
int arr[] = {2, 3, 4};
```

is just fine, and completely correct. No need to change.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "initialize an array", you have to initialize an *array*, not a pointer.

Anyway, in C99 *compound literals* can be used and a pointer can be initialized as

```
int *arr = (int []) {2, 3, 4};
```

which is close to what you were trying to do. Although the term "ANSI C" is often used to refer to C89/90, where this feature is not available.

There's nothing "better" about this approach. It just gives you a pointer instead of an array, so it is really a question of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Why would the second version be better than the first?

The first version at least is explicit: you define an int array, with the given elements. Let the compiler determine how to do this optimally.

Answer (score 1):

Going from your comment to Evan Li ("string is also kind of an array, and it is initialized with a pointer. Thus, arrays should be also initialized this way.").  If the instructor actually told you this, I'd seriously think about finding a new instructor, because he's confused about things.

A *string literal* is an array expression; the literal "Hello" is a 6-element array of `char` (`const char` in C++).  String literals are stored in such a way that their memory is allocated over the lifetime of the program; this memory may or may not be read-only, depending on the platform.  The behavior on attempting to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined*, meaning you may get a segfault, or the string may get modified, or something else happens.

When an array expression appears in a context other than as an operand to the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, then the type of the expression is converted ("decays") from "N-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

*That's* why you can write something like

```
char *foo = "This is a test";
```

The string literal `"This is a test"` is an array expression of type "15-element array of `char`";  since it isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or `&` operators, and isn't being used to initialize another array of `char`, the type of the expression becomes "pointer to `char`", and the address of the first character is assigned to `foo`.  By comparison,

```
char foo[] = "This is a test";
```

declares `foo` as an *array* of `char`; the size is computed from the size of the initializer string (15 characters), and the *contents* of the string literal are copied to `foo`.

A string is an array expression; a brace-enclosed list of values is *not*.

```
int *foo = {1, 2, 3};
```

won't create a 3-element array of `int` and assign the address of the first element to `foo`; instead, this *should* be a constraint violation if I'm reading [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) right:

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
> **Constraints**
> 2 No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity
> being initialized.

As of C99, you can use what are known as *compound literals*, like so:

```
int *foo = (int []) {1, 2, 3};
```

The cast-expression `(int [])` is required.  This does create a new 3-element array of `int` and assigns the address of the first element to `foo`.  Unlike string literals, compound literals like this only exist for the duration of the enclosing block<sup>1</sup>; IOW, if you did something like

```
int *foo = NULL;
if (condition())
{
  foo = (int []){1, 2, 3};
  // do stuff
}
// do more stuff
```

the anonymous array object pointed to by `foo` only exists within the `if` block; once the `if` block exits, the array no longer exists, and the value of `foo` is no longer valid.

---

<sup>1.  If the compound literal is defined at file scope (outside of any function), then it has `static` duration and exists for the lifetime of the program.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

int arr[] = {2, 3, 4}; is ok.

If you want to use pointer, you will have to allocate memory with for example malloc. Something like that :

```
  int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);

  arr[0]=1;
  arr[1]=2;
  arr[2]=3;
  arr[3]=4;

  //display
  printf("%d %d %d %d\n",arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]);

  free(arr);
```

Comment: Arrays are barely first class "objects" (things, etc) in C, so they decay to pointers smoothly. No reason to go through this just to get the pointer to the array from the "array" itself.

Comment: I wasn't telling him to use this way for his purpose right now but to show him how to allocate memory...